# Sliding Menu - How to add an activitity?

Tags: android, menu, slider, fragment

I am trying out sliding menu and so far it works. Now what I want is to associate an activity to the Fragment which I don't know how to do. This is what I have:
1) A sliding menu with few options
2) Upon selecting one options - now it loads an activity (it is a list activity) which I have. The problem is that when it loads that activity, I no longer able to pull out the sliding menu (I have to click back to back main screen). I know maybe this is due to I am not loading my activity as a fragment but instead as List Activity.

So how do I convert my listactivity into fragment?

My Code (in MainActivity to select that options)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MListActivity.class);
```

In the ListActivity.class, it is listing of all items:

```
public class MListActivity extends ListActivity {
```

Appreciate your help. Many thanks.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

     private String RSSFEEDURL = "https://sites.google.com/site/fappweb/Topmovies.xml";
     RSSFeed feed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "30"));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            //fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);



            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



}
```

What I did was to duplicate the main activity and rename as SlideActivity. Then in my MlistActivity I put it as extend SlideActivity as follows:

```
public class MListActivity extends SlideActivity {
```

But I got the following error when I try to start my MlistActivity:

05-25 18:20:20.404: E/FragmentManager(28565): No view found for id 0x7f0a0001 (com.fpbbnlsly.worldv:id/frame_container) for fragment HomeFragment{42a29d40 #0 id=0x7f0a0001}

Answer (score 0):

The sliding menu is associated with the current activity. The new activity you are starting doesn't have a sliding menu associated with it.

What you need to do is have a MyListFragment and add that fragment to your current activity.

```
Fragment fragment = new MyListFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
               .commit();

// Close the drawer
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Where R.id.content_frame is a  in your current activity.

Comment: ? Thanks for your answer. May I know where I put this code? Is it in my ListActivity or in my MainActivity when I call the new intent to open my ListActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the fragment option and keep swapping fragments in the same activity or you can attach an identical `SlidingMenu` to your new `ListActivity`

What I did was I created a class that implements activity and had it have a `SlidingMenu` then extended that class in all my activities or you can copy/paste the sliding menu code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // put sliding menu code here
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends MyActivity {
}

public class SecondActivity extends MyActivity {
}
```

NOTE: this is just pseudo code

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How do I create the Sliding Menu and extend that class for all my activities? i do not want to copy and paste all the codes as it is least efficient way of doing it. I just want the same sliding menu for all my activity.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but it returns error. I updated in my questions with my code and how I extend to my listactivity but it has some error. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Its different from wat I need

Comment: What are you looking for ?